# Three Drives. First with Windows 10, Second with Ubuntu, and Third of storage. Storage Driver visible from Windows but not from Ubuntu

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, hard-drive, windows-10

I'm having trouble with a 3TB hard drive. Thing is complicated, so I'll explain as detailed as I can.

This computer has 3 disc drives. 1 SSD and 2 HDD.
-The SSD has Windows 10 installed (Legacy Bios)
-The second Drive is the 3TB Storage disk
-The third drive is a 160GB HDD in which I installed Ubuntu 15.10

I've installed ubuntu in the third drive with 3 partitions, /Root, /Home, and Swap. And I'm using this drive as the first in boot priority, so the Grub let me boot between Ubuntu and Windows 10.

I've been updating the fresh install, and then noticed that the 3TB HDD is not visible from Ubuntu. My first though was: It's broken. But then, I logged into Windows and, there it was. The files are intact, and I can access them.

What is the problem?

Thanks

EDIT:

I've make sure that Windows is not Hibernating or using Hybrid Boot, and i have make sure that Windows has been properly shutted down

Comment: What's the output of `sudo lsblk -f`?

Answer (score 1):

Launch the `Disks` program from the launcher. The "Volumes" section will show you all the disks in your system.

Select your 3Tb HDD.

In the bar at the bottom of the Volumes diagram, click the gear wheels icon to bring up the settings for that disk.

Click on `Edit Mount Options`

Turn on the Auto Mount option, and make sure the 'show in user interface' option is ticked.

Then close Disks and reboot. Your drive should now show up in Nautilus.

Comment: It shows no Auto Mount Option, actually, it just doesn't let me mount at all.

Comment: @GinoMarínLeón I missed a step, my apologies - see edited answer.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes, this behavior arises when windows is not properly shutdown or you might have windows hibernated. In this case if you boot ubuntu it will not mount that drive. Hope this helps.

Comment: This will only result in a failure to mount the drive. It should still show up in the device list.